# what difference between propositions and `if` statement of program

Tags: logic, programming

Consider a proposition,
$$\forall x\in\mathbb{R}~(x^2<0\implies x=23)\tag{1}$$
Due to [vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth), Obviously it's a true proposition, However I have confused by it when transform this proposition to a program. Such as:

```
if(x² < 0){
  return 23;
}
```

We know the statement will never be executed, because x² always greater or equal than zero, I don't know, Does a mathematics proposition can be transformed to `if` statement in program, if my transformation is wrong, how to transform this proposition?

#### TABLE

```
A   B   T/F
___________
T | T | T
T | F | F
F | T | T
F | F | T
```

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing two uses of the combination  "if.....then".  In math it is a connective, a way of linking two sentences into one sentence.  We define that in "if A then B" if A is false the compound sentence is true.  In programming "if A then B" means "if A is true, do B, and if A is false do not do B".  These are not at all the same.

Programming languages like FORTRAN and Python also have a completely different meaning for the equals sign.  It is normal to write $I=I+1$ except in Python you use lower case.  The equals sign is not what mathematicians use it for, it is a direction to compute the right hand side and store that in the address indicated by the left hand side.  The left side has to be essentially a single variable.

In English, whether you consider "if A then B" to be true when A is false is ambiguous.  If I say "If 2+2=5 then the moon is made of green cheese." is that true, false, or nonsense?  I think most people would opt for nonsense.  In English "if ..... then" has a sense of the first causing the second.  In math it is clearly true.

Meanings change due to context.

Comment: Thanks, I have to say `"If 2+2=5 then the moon is made of green cheese."`, It's no proposition is `if the moon is **not** made of green cheese, then 2+2 ≠ 5`, It's true. In addition `except in Python you use lower case` implies what? It seems to out of my knowledges.

Comment: In Python the tradition is to use lower case variable names for most things, while FORTRAN was originally written on cards that used only upper case.  I speak some Python but with a heavy FORTRAN accent.  My English point is that most people understand there to be a causative link between the two clauses of an if...then statement.  It is definitely not the same as the math approach that makes it equivalent to $2+2 \neq 5$ or the moon is made of green cheese.  Nobody would say that outside of a logic course.

Comment: So, you mean that the proposition of mathematics couldn't equivalent to `if( p ){ q }` of a program in simply way?  If I would write a code to process such proposition, I need to look at p => q( table) and according to the table to response. Such as this proposition in my question. Because it always true, hence the corresponding program would be `judge_proposition(x){ return true}` whatever the `x`  is what real value, Right?

Comment: You can have a statement "if p then q" in programming if p and q are Boolean variables.  I am not aware of a language that provides that, but they all will do (not p) or q, which is the same thing.  You could then just say return ((not p) or q) and it will give you the truth value as a return.  You can also use (not p) or q in a more complex expression.  This is completely different from the programming if p then q, which is a directive, not a logical statement.  q is not a Boolean variable here, it is an executable statement.

Comment: Thanks, So, process a proposition in programming, We need to compare it with the **TABLE** which is emphasized in my question. Right?

Comment: I would say yes, but it feels like something is bothering you that I don't understand.

Comment: I have been confused by propositions in mathematics and the programming statement `if(condition){do somethings }else{ do other things }`, I mixed them and  assumed they are equivalent **until** you have answered this answers. I understand they are not the same things at all. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The material implication symbol $\implies$ (which is sometimes called the "if" symbol) is pretty much totally unrelated to if-statements in computer programming.

In classical logic (the kind of logic that mathematicians use 95% of the time, perhaps), the statement $p \implies q$ is simply an abbreviation of $(\neg p) \lor q$. It means exactly that, no more, no less.

So, the correct way to translate $x^2 < 0 \implies x = 23$ into computer code would be something like this:

```
function my_predicate(x) {
    let p = (x² < 0);
    let q = (x == 23);
    return ((!p) || q);
}
```

Then the sentence $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}~(x^2<0\implies x=23)$ is equivalent to the assertion that the function `my_predicate` is equivalent to the function `always_true`, as defined like so:

```
function always_true(x) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What does your `my_predicate ` base on? Does it base on P => Q(table)? According to my understanding about proposition, A no proposition is equivalent to the original proposition, However, in your  `my_predicate `, you only do `not p`. If invoke `my_predicate(1)`, then your function would return false. How to interpret this?

Comment: @jackX I'm afraid I don't know what you mean by "base on". I also don't know what you mean when you say that "A no proposition is equivalent to the original proposition". In any case, `my_predicate(1)` will come out to true, not false. This is because `(x² < 0)` is `(1² < 0)`, which is `false`, so `p` gets set to `false`, and so `!p` is `true`, so `(!p) || q` is `true`.

Comment: "base on" means why `!p`, Does it according to the (p=>q table which is in my question **TABLE**)?

Comment: I saw your Skeptics SE [answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/47879) and noticed that you have joined HSM SE but have no posts there where I could comment. You may find this answerable as well: [What exactly was Lagrange's “grave mistake” with respect to rotating bodies under hydrostatic equilibrium?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/11351/3869)

Comment: @uhoh I don't know the answer to that question, but thank you for letting me know about it!

Comment: @jackX If I understand your question correctly, the answer is yes: my code contains `!p` because of that truth table. By the way, it sounds like when you say "no proposition", you mean "contrapositive". You shouldn't use the phrase "no proposition"; that phrase is extremely confusing.

Comment: @TannerSwett Thanks, It's exactly my meaning, namely, According to **TABLE**